# How do I find all the rows containing the specified substring

Tags: mysql

Currently I'm doing this, but it requires to give the full string , also all column names

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE   "Homepage" IN (column1, colum2, ..... Column N);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. There’s the slowest way:

```
WHERE (page_visited LIKE '%Homepage%') OR (visitor_id LIKE '%Homepage%')
```

There’s the slow and expensive way:

```
WHERE CONCAT(page_visited, '|', visitor_id) LIKE '%Homepage%'
```

<sub>**Note:** The pipe (`|`) is there to prevent a match being the result of a concatenation.</sub>

There’s the inefficient way:

```
WHERE LOCATE('Homepage', page_visited) + LOCATE('Homepage', visitor_id) > 0
```

There’s also the individual-lookup way:

```
SELECT * FROM events
 WHERE page_visited LIKE '%Homepage%'
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM events
 WHERE visitor_id LIKE '%Homepage%'
```

More information would need to be known about the table being queried as well as the columns (Is `visitor_id` a typo?), the goal of the result set, and how often the query is called in order to recommend any of the more complete solutions.

Comment: Hey sorry, I have edited the question. I need to do this for all columns not the specified columns.

Comment: If you must do it for all columns, then your query performance is doomed. Add a column as a very wide `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`, then create a trigger that fires on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` to write the value of every queryable field to that new column. From there you can either use `LIKE` or a full-text search.